# How to update/set a label within Python 3.5 + PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, label, pyqt5

I have an form created with Qt designer. The form must open a file by an filedialog. This works all fine.

But i'm not able to update the label with the selected file path. When i place the code for the filedialog directly in the label code the label is set correctly.

Part of the code is as follows:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QFileDialog

class Ui_Form(QWidget):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(499, 297)
        self.toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(Form)
        self.toolButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 150, 25, 19))
        self.toolButton.setObjectName("toolButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 180, 311, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))

        self.toolButton.setText(_translate("Form", "..."))
        self.toolButton.clicked.connect(self.InputFile)

        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))

    def InputFile(self):
        print("Input file printing")
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Select File", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)")
        if fileName:
            InputLabel = fileName
            print(InputLabel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can't you just put `self.label.setText(QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate("Form", fileName))` in the `InputFile` method? Worked fine for me https://i.gyazo.com/e4e918101de2e9f517f7691cd75783d2.png

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I tried to use/call the variable `_translate` from `_translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate`. But that obviously doesn't work because of a different function variable._translate